# How to make Jackson type id resolver work on a collection of generic objects?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a class defined as follows. The input field is a collection of objects that can be either a number or string. I want to make sure that if an object is a number, it is always converted to a Long object(not Integer, even if an Integer object is big enough). So I tried to use a customized type id resolver but it does not work on collection. I've did some experiments and found that if a field is solo object, then it works.

My question is that how to make Jackson type id resolver work on a collection of generic objects?

```
public class Expression <T extends Comparable<T>> extends BooleanExpressionInput<Set<T>> {
    @JsonProperty("input")
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    @JsonTypeIdResolver(CustomTypeIdResolver.class)
    private Set<T> input;
}
```

The CustomTypeIdResolver class used above is defined as:

```
public class QueryIndexTypeIdResolver extends TypeIdResolverBase
{
    @Override
    public String idFromValue(Object o)
    {
        return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public String idFromValueAndType(Object o, Class<?> aClass)
    {
        return o.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public JsonTypeInfo.Id getMechanism()
    {
        return JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public JavaType typeFromId(DatabindContext context, String id) throws IOException
    {
        if (JSON_VALUE_TYPE_RESOLVER_MAP.containsKey(id)) {
            Class resolvedClass = JSON_VALUE_TYPE_RESOLVER_MAP.get(id);
            return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructSpecializedType(TypeFactory.unknownType(), resolvedClass);
        }

        return super.typeFromId(context, id);
    }
}
```

The resolver map used above is defined as:

```
public static final ImmutableMap<String, Class> JSON_VALUE_TYPE_RESOLVER_MAP = new ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Class>()
            .put("Integer", Long.class)
            .put("Long", Long.class)
            .put("String", String.class)
            .build();
```